# How to request scope/permission from Facebook during user registration

Tags: php, facebook, scope, user-permissions

I am using the information on http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ to register, and login users with Facebook. How would I request this permission? I've tried to use

```
 &scope=permission,permission,etc,etc
```

before fields, and then after fields. Regardless, the system still says

```
The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action
```

Any help on this issue would be much appreciated!

---

After registration, I try as follows and it still spit out the same error:

```
        if ($_REQUEST) {
            require 'facebook.php';
            $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => APP_ID,'secret' => APP_SECRET));
            $user = $facebook->getUser();
            if ($user) {
                $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,publish_stream'));
                $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> 'Testing posting to may wall', 'cb' => ''));
            } else {
              $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                    array('scope' => 'email,publish_stream','redirect_uri'  => REDIRECT_URL )
                );
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to request permissions after registration seperately. There is no way to request permissions through registration plugin at the moment.

This feature is on the wishlist: 
http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=14733

Comment: Will you please give me some pointers as to how to request permission separately? I am new to facebook api. For example, when I get to the redirect page, where I am reading the signed_request, how would I request the permission? I am using the code facebook provides at the bottom of http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/ to read the request.

Comment: Have you look at the Facebook login plugin? For your case, maybe it would be better to use it instead of registration plugin? Or you can use login plugin to request permissions after registration. Check this link for uses of registration plugin and decide yourself which one to use: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/440/

Comment: After registration, I try as follows and it still spit out the same error:


if ($_REQUEST) {
   require 'facebook.php';
   $facebook = new Facebook(array('appId'  => APP_ID,'secret' => APP_SECRET));
   $user = $facebook->getUser();
 if ($user) {
    $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'email,publish_stream'));
  $statusUpdate = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array('message'=> 'Testing posting to may wall', 'cb' => ''));
   } else {
   $loginUrl   = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
   array('scope' => 'email,publish_stream','redirect_uri'  => REDIRECT_URL )
  );
 }
}